# Allowing multiple, user-selectable MFA registration methods with Azure AD B2C user flows or custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

Is it possible to have multiple, user-selectable registration methods when users sign up for multi-factor authentication (MFA) in Azure AD B2C? E.g., primary and secondary MFA registration methods.

Here is an example:

[image: Azure AD MFA Registration Methods]

We know it is possible to have a *single* user-selectable MFA registration method as exemplified here:

- [mfa-email-or-phone](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone/policy/SignUpOrSignin_PhoneOrEmailMFA.xml)

But we are having trouble determining how to configure *multiple* user-selectable MFA registration methods.

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Note that: With user flows, only one authentication method can be
> selected while enabling MFA.

I created an Azure AD B2C user flow and enforced MFA like the below:

[image]

The user gets the prompt while signing in like below:

[image]

If you want to configure other authentication methods then, you must update the user flow by the authentication methods based on your requirement.

**Note**: There are limited customization possibilities for user flows, hence you can **make use of custom policies** to configure MFA.

For sample,

An authenticator app must be installed by the user on a device that belongs to them.
The user uses the authenticator app to manually enter a code or scan a QR code on their initial sign-up or sign-in.
The user enters the TOTP code that displays on the authenticator app on subsequent sign-ins.
For more in detail on how to **configure MFA using custom policies** refer to the below MsDoc:

[MsDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#set-multifactor-authentication)

[MsDoc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/895106/enable-both-phone-and-totp-methods-in-azure-b2c-ca) - by Sandeep G-MSFT

Comment: Thanks Sourav. Does this mean custom policies allow multiple MFA authentication methods? If so, are these methods user-selectable or must be defined in the custom policy flows?

Comment: @HXK8, AFAIK these are not user selectable they must be configured in custom policies.